# Return NULL instead of 0 when using COUNT(column) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case

I have query  which running fine and its doing two types of work, `COUNT`  and `SUM`.

Something like

```
select 
    id,
    Count (contracts) as countcontracts,
    count(something1),
    count(something1),
    count(something1),
    sum(cost) as sumCost
from 
    table
group by 
    id
```

My problem is: if there is no contract for a given ID, it will return 0 for `COUNT` and `Null` for `SUM`. I want to see null instead of 0

I was thinking about case when `Count (contracts) = 0 then null else Count (contracts) end` but I don't want to do it this way because I have more than 12 count positions in query and its prepossessing big amount of records so I think it may slow down query performance.

Is there any other ways to replace 0 with `NULL`?

Comment: Do a CTE, replace at main/outer level.

Comment: cant do CTE its already  part of CTE :) it also part of insert

Comment: IIF is a short way than case-when-else-end:
IIF(expression,truepart,falsepart)

Comment: Just so you know, when you have something like `when <function> (contracts) = 0 then null else <function> (contracts) end`, the function is not executed twice. The result is cached and used in both places. So there is no additional overhead. It just looks clunky and verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select NULLIF ( Count(something) , 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are three methods:

```
1. (case when count(contracts) > 0 then count(contracts) end) as countcontracts
2. sum(case when contracts is not null then 1 end) as countcontracts
3. nullif(count(contracts), 0)
```

All three of these require writing more complicated expressions.  However, this really isn't that difficult.  Just copy the line multiple times, and change the name of the variable on each one.  Or, take the current query, put it into a spreadsheet and use spreadsheet functions to make the transformation.  Then copy the function down.  (Spreadsheets are really good code generators for repeated lines of code.)

Comment: I am not sure that  case its good idea because its is the part of the query  which already  has more than 14 CTE few case statements in it and one UPDATE  :) be honest  don't think adding 14 addition cases will not gona affect performance

Comment: NullIf method is the best, but in your example there's a mistake, it should be nullif(count(contracts), 0)